# How to shuffle and paginate data with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

I want to shuffle and paginate data in laravel.

when I use this code  :

```
`$questions = Question::where("exam_id",$exam->id)->shuffle()->paginate(1);`
```

gives me this error : **BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::shuffle()**
and when I use this code:

```
$questions = Question::where("exam_id",$exam->id)->paginate(1)->shuffle();
```

in `dd($questions = Question::where("exam_id",$exam->id)->paginate(1)->shuffle());`gives me a collection that has the first item and other items don't exist. And there is also no paging information.And when I don't use `dd()` gives me this error : **Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.** While I use `$questions->links()` in the
**view**.
When I use this code :

```
$questions = Question::where("exam_id",$exam->id)->get()->shuffle()->paginate(1);
```

Gives me this error : **Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.**

And when I use this code :

```
$questions = Question::where("exam_id",$exam->id)->inRandomOrder()->paginate(1);
```

It works, but the data is repeated on later pages. For example, the data on the first page may be repeated on page seven or other pages.

**In fact, I want the data to be sorted by random And then paginated so that when a data is loaded on one page not repeated on subsequent pages.**

**please help me!!Thanks**

Comment: to reach exactly what you want, there is no easy good solution. either take all the data in random order, send them to the client(browser) then paginate them with a javascript plugin (datatable or other) OR set an order field in your database than changes over time (once a day for example) and use it as the order for your query and just paginate it normaly (no shuffle). If you want to shuffle just the element of the same page, then there is an easy solution.

Comment: One possible solution would be to develop a custom paginator. In the first request, you get all ids in random order, save somewhere (session/database), then retrieve only that slice of data each page. It might be a problem if you have a large table.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem and solved it by adding the shuffle()->all() methods to the collection variable in the view file, which seems to work perfectly.

Once you pass the variable to the view to loop over using a foreach I added the following:

`$rows->shuffle()->all()`

So my foreach loop looks like:

`foreach($rows->shuffle()->all() as $row){ ... }`

The rows on the front end when loaded using ajax still work as they should with the paginator since the collection is untouched and the selection of the next rows is correctly loaded and then shuffled, meaning there are no duplicates.